# Why is (V)SHUFPS not in Intel's constant time instruction list?

Tags: assembly, cryptography, x86-64, cpu-architecture, avx

Earlier this year Intel published a [list](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/software-security-guidance/resources/data-operand-independent-timing-instructions.html) of instructions that are guaranteed not to have timing dependency on its data operands. (Initially it was suggested that these are constant-time only when DOITM is enabled, but later it was [clarified](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/851920c5-31c9-ddd9-3e2d-57d379aa0671@intel.com/) that these are always constant-time, regardless of DOITM.) Out of curiosity I am looking at how closely real-world crypto implementations conform to this list (i.e. only using instructions from this list).

It turns out this list has a number of oddities. It has `MOVDQU`, but not `MOVUPS`, even though the two should be functionally identical. This is not a serious issue: I can simply take the assembly output of the compiler, and do `sed 's/movups/movdqu/g'` before assembling.

A more difficult obstacle is that it does not have `(V)SHUFPS`, even though it clearly has lots of other floating point shuffling instructions like `VPERMILPS/D`. `SHUFPS` is [used](https://github.com/BLAKE3-team/BLAKE3/blob/master/c/blake3_avx512.c#L5) in BLAKE3.

Is there a known reason this instruction is not included on the constant-time list? What would be a good way to simulate its functionality, using only instructions from this list?

Comment: Following this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983569/implications-of-using-mm-shuffle-ps-on-integer-vector), I think a possible workaround is to use pshufd (shuffle 32-bit within 128-bit lane) plus vpblendd (blend two 128-bit lane).

Comment: On Skylake at least, some instructions have bypass latency that depends on which execution port it picked (and/or what port the input came from or output is going to, IIRC from Intel's optimization manual).  Like with `andps` between FP math instructions.  Makes me wonder if maybe `shufps` on Ice Lake might depend on whether it gets scheduled to port 1 or port 5.  That wouldn't be *data* dependent, even though non-constant, so might actually be good for introducing noise to timing attacks.  But if there's extra latency, it might only be for forwarding to some instruction types.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot find an answer to the first question (why it is not in the list), but I have a solution to the second question, namely how to workaround this instruction. For the BLAKE3 implementation, the problematic line is

```c
#define _mm_shuffle_ps2(a, b, c)                                               \
  (_mm_castps_si128(                                                           \
      _mm_shuffle_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps(a), _mm_castsi128_ps(b), (c))))
```

A drop in replacement is

```c
#define _mm_shuffle_ps2(a, b, c) \
      _mm_blend_epi32 (_mm_shuffle_epi32((a), (c)), _mm_shuffle_epi32((b), (c)), 0b1100)
```

This causes GCC to generate `VPSHUFD` and `VPBLENDD`, both of which should be constant-time according to Intel.